# Android drawing bitmap multiple times and then onScroll causes ANR

Tags: java, android, multithreading, surfaceview

I want to do `canvas.drawBitmap(...)` multiple times but now app freezes (ANR) once I move my SurfaceView (call         `surfaceView.setX(gs.moveX); surfaceView.setY(gs.moveY);`  in `onScroll(...)`) in my SurfaceView class with custom GestureDetector. This SurfaceView flow is controlled by GameThread in which I draw 3 times `canvas.drawBitmap(...)`. What is worth noticing is that when I comment out second or third `canvas.drawBitmap(...)` from `drawTmxMaps(...)` then app scrolls almost correctly - almost because it works but scrolling is laggy.

So how to solve my problem?

Here is my code.

Loader.java

```
private static Map<Integer, Bitmap[]> differentFramesMap = new HashMap<>();
private static Map<Integer, Canvas[]> differentCanvasesMap = new HashMap<>();

(...)

public static void drawTmxMaps(Canvas canvas, Context context) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(differentFramesMap.get(0)[framesFirstAnimIter], 0, 0, PaintTemplates.getInstance(context).pMap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(differentFramesMap.get(1)[framesSecondAnimIter], 0, 0, PaintTemplates.getInstance(context).pMap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(differentFramesMap.get(2)[framesThirdAnimIter], 0, 0, PaintTemplates.getInstance(context).pMap);

    if (!isIterStarted) {
        iterTmxFrames();
        isIterStarted = true;
    }
}

private static void iterTmxFrames() {
    runnable = () -> {
        framesFirstAnimIter++;
        framesSecondAnimIter++;
        framesThirdAnimIter++;
        if (framesFirstAnimIter == 3)
            framesFirstAnimIter = 0;
        if (framesSecondAnimIter == 2)
            framesSecondAnimIter = 0;
        if (framesThirdAnimIter == 2)
            framesThirdAnimIter = 0;
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}
```

MyThread.java

```
    @Override
public void run() {
    while (isRunning) {
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
        if (canvas != null) {
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {

                TmxLoader.drawTmxMaps(canvas, gameSurface.getContext());

                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }

        loopTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        if (loopTime < delay) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay - loopTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("Interupted ex", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT after answer**

Now there is no ANR but the surface seems not to refresh because thre are old positions of canvas on the screen. It looks like this:

[image]

Solved by simply adding `canvas.drawARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);` as a first method in GameThread run().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

**Loader.java:**

```
public class Loader {
private static Map<Integer, Bitmap[]> differentFramesMap = new HashMap<>();
private static Map<Integer, Canvas[]> differentCanvasesMap = new HashMap<>();
private static boolean isIterStarted = false;
private static int framesFirstAnimIter = 0;
private static int framesSecondAnimIter = 0;
private static int framesThirdAnimIter = 0;
private static Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private static Runnable runnable;

public static void drawTmxMaps(Canvas canvas, Context context) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(differentFramesMap.get(0)[framesFirstAnimIter], 0, 0, PaintTemplates.getInstance(context).pMap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(differentFramesMap.get(1)[framesSecondAnimIter], 0, 0, PaintTemplates.getInstance(context).pMap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(differentFramesMap.get(2)[framesThirdAnimIter], 0, 0, PaintTemplates.getInstance(context).pMap);

    if (!isIterStarted) {
        iterTmxFrames();
        isIterStarted = true;
    }
}

private static void iterTmxFrames() {
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            framesFirstAnimIter++;
            framesSecondAnimIter++;
            framesThirdAnimIter++;
            if (framesFirstAnimIter == 3)
                framesFirstAnimIter = 0;
            if (framesSecondAnimIter == 2)
                framesSecondAnimIter = 0;
            if (framesThirdAnimIter == 2)
                framesThirdAnimIter = 0;
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}
}
```

**MyThread.java:**

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
private final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private final GameSurface gameSurface;
private boolean isRunning;
private long delay = 33; // 30 FPS
private long startTime;
private long loopTime;
private float scrollX;
private float scrollY;

public MyThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GameSurface gameSurface) {
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    this.gameSurface = gameSurface;
}

public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    isRunning = running;
}

public void setScroll(float scrollX, float scrollY) {
    this.scrollX = scrollX;
    this.scrollY = scrollY;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (isRunning) {
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
        if (canvas != null) {
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                canvas.translate(-scrollX, -scrollY);
                Loader.drawTmxMaps(canvas, gameSurface.getContext());
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
        loopTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        if (loopTime < delay) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay - loopTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("Interrupted ex", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, there is a progress hehe, no ANR but I added my current screenshot when I move canvas, what happen then.

Answer (score 1):

Your **'MyThread'** class appears to be drawing everything on the main UI thread. As a result, the UI freezes due to more work.

The best way to avoid this is to create a **'Runnable'** that performs the drawing and forwards it to the **'Handler'** on its own thread.

Here is how you can modify your code to accomplish this:

Loader.java

```
    public static void drawTmxMaps(Canvas canvas, Context context) {
    Canvas[] canvases = differentCanvasesMap.get(0);
    Bitmap[] bitmaps = differentFramesMap.get(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {
        canvases[i].drawBitmap(bitmaps[i], 0, 0, PaintTemplates.getInstance(context).pMap);
    }
    if (!isIterStarted) {
        iterTmxFrames();
        isIterStarted = true;
    }
}

private static void iterTmxFrames() {
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            framesFirstAnimIter++;
            framesSecondAnimIter++;
            framesThirdAnimIter++;
            if (framesFirstAnimIter == 3) {
                framesFirstAnimIter = 0;
            }
            if (framesSecondAnimIter == 2) {
                framesSecondAnimIter = 0;
            }
            if (framesThirdAnimIter == 2) {
                framesThirdAnimIter = 0;
            }

            // Post the drawing to a handler on a separate thread
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Canvas[] canvases = differentCanvasesMap.get(0);
                    Bitmap[] bitmaps = differentFramesMap.get(0);
                    for (int i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {
                        canvases[i].drawBitmap(bitmaps[i], 0, 0, null);
                    }
                }
            });

            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}
```

In the **'drawTmxMaps()'** method, a loop is created to iterate over each canvas and bitmap and draw them all at one time.

In the **'iterTmxFrames()'** method, we use a **'Handler'** to post a **'Runnable'** where it separates the threads every 1000ms.

The **'Runnable'** performs the actual drawing on the canvas utilizing the bitmaps from **'differentFramesMap'**

In the **'MyThread'** class, call **'Loader.drawTmxMaps()'** to draw the bitmaps. Following this, **'surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)**' can be used to post the resulting **'Canvas'** objects to the **'SurfaceHolder'**.

After this, **'SurfaceView'** should no longer freeze or lag when scrolling.

In fact, SurfaceView should be moved from the main UI thread to a separate thread

1. Create a new thread to handle the surfaceView movement.

   private class MoveSurfaceViewThread extends Thread {
   private final SurfaceView surfaceView;
   private final float moveX;
   private final float moveY;

   public MoveSurfaceViewThread(SurfaceView surfaceView, float moveX, float moveY) {
   this.surfaceView = surfaceView;
   this.moveX = moveX;
   this.moveY = moveY;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
   surfaceView.setX(moveX);
   surfaceView.setY(moveY);
   }
   }
2. In your custom GestureDetector, create an instance of the
   MoveSurfaceViewThread and start it on scroll

   ```
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, 
    float distanceY) {
    float moveX = gameSurface.getX() - distanceX;
    float moveY = gameSurface.getY() - distanceY;

    // Create a new thread to move the surfaceView
    MoveSurfaceViewThread moveSurfaceViewThread = new 
    MoveSurfaceViewThread(gameSurface, moveX, moveY);
    moveSurfaceViewThread.start();
    return true;
    }
   ```

Putting SurfaceView on a separate thread will make the app more responsive and prevent the UI thread from being blocked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but your code does not draw those bitmaps[] at all :(. None of the bitmaps is drawn

Comment: Maybe I should also modify something in MyThread?

Comment: Hope the edited answer will help you

Comment: so great so see you remember me :). Tommorow I will test it out, but write me how exactly should MyThread looks like?